# CORS issue in Chrome though Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is present

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, cors

A developer added new DELETE blog endpoint, whose source code is based on the existing and working DELETE page endpoint. It works on his PC but it fails on my PC. The Chrome does not run the DELETE method because of allegedly missing CORS header.

The attached picture shows Chrome dev tools screenshots for three different OPTION + DELETE/POST requests. I have checked that OPTIONS is always run for DELETE page request and it returns a CORS header for localhost. The response is the same as for POST a picture or DELETE a page. I cannot see any difference and I cannot find an explanation.

Backend is written in NodeJS

This code works on my PC:
https://github.com/literakl/mezinamiridici/blob/master/backend/src/handlers/pages/deletePage.js

```
module.exports = (app) => {
  app.options('/v1/pages/:pageId', auth.cors);
  app.delete('/v1/pages/:pageId', auth.required, auth.cms_admin, auth.cors, async (req, res) => {
```

This code works on developer's Chrome and Firefox but fails on my Chrome or Edge
https://github.com/literakl/mezinamiridici/blob/master/backend/src/handlers/items/deleteBlog.js

```
module.exports = (app) => {
  app.options('/v1/blog/:blogId', auth.cors);    
  app.delete('/v1/blog/:blogId', auth.required, auth.cors, async (req, res) => {
```

[image]

Frontend is written in Vue. The page with Delete button is loaded from http://localhost:8080/p/leos/b/wing-suit-2. OPTIONS returns:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type,Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8080
```

Blocked DELETE request contains these request headers:

```
Origin: http://localhost:8080
Referer: http://localhost:8080/
```

So I assume that everything is set up correctly. Where is the issue please?

[image]

Update 1:

console log:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/v1/blog/1f3j20k5qh'
> from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

Comment: One interesting point is that Chrome shows the DELETE request prior the OPTIONS request. The header has the same date (till seconds). On the other hand other requests are displayed in this order too and they do work.

Comment: Few more findings: I have returned home. The problem is gone. Could it be caused by different WiFi?

Answer (score -1):

One thing I see is that the value in the header is different in the options call than in your delete call, specifically its less restrictive, might be that browsers take issue with that

Comment: Please be concrete. Which value do you mind?

Comment: I can see the only difference in the date.

Comment: Look more clearly, your acces-control-allow-origin header has a specific host value in your options call and a * in the actual delete call

Comment: I am sorry, I do not see what you mean. I cannot see it. Please type the line you mean.

Comment: I mean the response headers: your access-control-allow-origin header has the value http://localhost;8080 in the options call and the value * in your delete/post/get calls

Comment: Interesting point. But this is a response from the server for cors protected operation. The options response matters. And all browsers decide not to submit the delete request. I see in there logs that the delete is not executed.